# Unable to set new owner of system in Registry

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry, administrator, ownership

I am trying to set myself as the owner of  the systems file in the Windows 10 Registry to enable Task Manager.  I am not the admin so when I click Apply I am given the message:

> Unable to set new owner on System Access Denied.

Is there a way to bypass this? I have looked at similar questions but none of them answered what I am trying to do. I am not able to download anything on the computer or contact the admin.

Comment: *owner of the systems file* what is the systems file in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

#### No.

The operation you're trying to perform is reserved for users with administrative permissions. If working around this was an option, then the distinction between users authorized to perform the action (administrators) and users *not* authorized (standard users) would be meaningless.

You need to contact the administrator and either have them do this, or grant you the rights to do it yourself.